# I have an error when i try to implement yolov4 on webcam: Could not find module yolo_cpp_dll.dll' (or one of its dependencies

Tags: python, object-detection, yolov4

Message=Could not find module yolo_cpp_dll.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

i downloaded the code from here: https://github.com/augmentedstartups/YOLOv4-Tutorials/blob/master/3.%20YOLOv4%20Video%20and%20Webcam/darknet_video_mod.py

the massage happens in darknet.py when I try to run the above python file in the link.
enter image description here.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIdXv.png)

Comment: Could you please attach your code instead of a screenshot? it's easier to try and repro that way. 

Also, did you compile the darknet.dll on your machine?

Comment: yes, thank  you, i have solved the issue. after multiple times it compiled.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.